# Writing a code to change the position of a image in Visual Basic in ms word

Tags: vba, ms-word

As ms word does not allow to record a macro to change the position of a already-inserted & selected image I need to write a macro in visual basic.

It needs to do the following:
 1. Give the selected pic a border
 2. Change its position to the lower end of the page.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  You might begin by doing a similar "record macro" in Excel.  While the Worksheet/Document object is not the same, the `Shapes` collection is similar enough that you can probably get started, and if you use the Word Object Browser, you can probably resolve this on your own.

Comment: even if you not able to start coding on your own it's difficult to help you as your question is not precise. If you expect any support you must be very, very precise... So, is there only one pic? is it located in text (`InlineShape`) or floating (`Shape`)? what does it mean `lower end of the page` -there is nothing like that, explain in details!

Comment: @KazJaw It is only one pic. Pics inserted into a word document is by default inline. All I want to do is to put a border & change it to a floating one (via macro). Forget about the 'lower end of the page'. Please comment if you want any other information. Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is only one `InlineShape` in document (`ActiveDocument`) the following code can solve your both needs:

```
Sub qSolved()

    With ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(1)
        'border
        .Line.Weight = xlThin
        'conversion to Shape
        .ConvertToShape
    End With

    'bonus :) -if you need to set position of newly created Shape
    With ActiveDocument.Shapes(1)
        .Top = 100
        .Left = 100
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You are great!! Thats the thing I want. It worked perfectly.. :)

Comment: I have a problem. Actually there is more than 1 picture in the document. I want to select each one individually, hit the macro button & it will give a border & change it to floating one(only that picture, not others). Can you please update the code? I'm sorry for your wasted effort because of my wrong interpretation of the problem.

Comment: Try to change `With ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(1)` into `With Selection.InlineShapes(1)`. Bonus section could not work properly therefore either remove it or try to change first line into: `With ActiveDocument.Shapes(ActiveDocument.Shapes.Count)`

Comment: Your code works fine, but except one thing: when the image floats, the texts in the documents does not automatically adjusts itself to give space for that picture inside the document. How to write a code for this??

Comment: @SumitPal, this will not be as easy as it seems to be, I think. My suggestion for you is to ask another question describing this new problem.